# how to go inside a specific directory and run commands inside it in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a gradle command inside a jenkins pipeline and for that i should `cd <location>` where gradle files are.
I added a cd command inside my pipeline but that is not working. I did this

```
 stage('build & SonarQube Scan') {
    withSonarQubeEnv('sonarhost') {
      sh 'cd  $WORKSPACE/sonarqube-scanner-gradle/gradle-basic'
      sh 'echo ${PWD}'
      sh 'gradle tasks --all'
      sh 'gradle sonarqube --debug'
    } 
  }
```

But the cd is not working, I tried dir step as suggested in pipeline docs, but i want to cd inside $WORKSPACE folder.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins resets the directory after each command. So after the first sh, it goes back to the previous location. The `dir` command is the correct approach, but it should be used like this:

```
dir('') {
}
```

Similar to how you have used `withSonarQubeEnv`

Alternatively, you can simply chain all the commands

```
sh 'cd $WORKSPACE/sonarqube-scanner-gradle/gradle-basic & echo ${PWD} & ...'
```

But this is not recommended. Since this will all be in the same command, it will run fine though.